# what is the action hook code to supporting product category condition in single product page of woocommerce?

Tags: categories, hooks, actions, conditional-tags

I want to display product attributes of 2 different product category with the help of conditional tags. But the condition was not working

```
This is the condition that i given
```

Height:get('height'); ?>
Width:get('width'); ?>
Thickness:get('thickness'); ?>
Frame Size:get('frame_size'); ?>
Weight after packing:get('weight_after_packing'); ?>





Large:get('large'); ?>
Medium:get('medium'); ?>
Small:get('small'); ?>

```
If the condition is working with the help of action hook. But i am not aware abt that .Can u pls help me...
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  Are you wanting to hook in something to a single product page or product category archive?

Comment: I want hook to a single product page

Comment: is_product() for all single product pages or is_product('slug') for specific product page

Comment: <?php if ( is_product('t-shirt') ) 
{?>
<table style="font-size:18px; line-height:25px; color:#513102; width:400px; height:200px;">
<tr><td>Height:-</td><td><?php echo $cfs->get('height'); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Width:-</td><td><?php echo $cfs->get('width'); ?></td></tr>
</table>
<?php } else
{?>

<table style="margin-top:20px; width:200px; height:100px; font-size:14px;" id="tt">
<tr><td>Large:-</td><td><?php echo $cfs->get('large'); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Medium:-</td><td><?php echo $cfs->get('medium'); ?></td></tr>

</table>
<?php
}?>

Comment: hi dis is my code but d condition is not working

Comment: Your question isn't clear however i have provided the conditionals for both category and single product.

Comment: http://bibleplanet.in/?product=i-belong-to-jesus                this is a single product page of 't-shirt' product category                           http://bibleplanet.in/?product=jesus-3                      this is also a single product page of other category     but in both category will display the same fields names called "width, height, thickness, frame size"   in case of t-shirt i want to display the field names like "large, medium, small ..etc" with the help of custom field suite plugin i implement all these things and i introduce this condition called <?php if(is_product('t-shirt'))

Comment: but condition was not working both if and else part have tables can u have any idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this conditional returns true on category archives for Woo Commerce and NOT single product page.

Try using the actual slug in lowercase or the i.d.

Example:

```
  if ( is_product_category( 't-shirt' ) ) {
```

Your code looks like its wrong because it includes too many brackets.

Woo suggest using the slug in their Docs.

This is the correct conditional which returns true on a single product page.

```
is_product()
```

Here's all the Woo hooks & conditional tags you can use in custom functions from your child themes functions file.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/