# Hook Widget to Woo Theme in functions.php

Tags: hooks

Right now I am adding a sidebar above my woocommerce products. How can I hook the sidebar to my theme.

Have registered sidebar and it works.

```
register_sidebar( 
    array( 
        'name'          => __( 'Filters', 'woothemes' ), 
        'id'            => 'filters', 
        'description'   => __( 'Optional widgetized shop page (displays only if widgets are added here).', 'woothemes' ), 
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">', 
        'after_widget'  => '</div>', 
        'before_title'  => '<h3>', 
        'after_title'   => '</h3>' 
    ) 
);
```

This is the hook I have used without success.

```
add_action( 'woo_main_before', 'woo_sidebar' );
function woo_sidebar() {
if (is_woocommerce()) { 
    echo '<div class="primary">';
        woo_sidebar( 'filters' );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

*Update: Using the code below adds this widget area to all other widget areas. Example: In the footer of www.lne.net.au.

```
add_action( 'woo_main_before', 'woo_sidebar' );
function woo_sidebar() {
if (is_woocommerce()) { 
    echo '<div class="primary">';
    dynamic_sidebar( 'filters' );
    echo '</div>';
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say "without success"?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve here ? can you please provide some more details ?

Comment: I mean the code doesn't work. Used @Subharanjan code dynamic_sidebar below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yey! Finally found a solution, replacing the depreciated hook `woo_sidbar` with `woocommerce_sidebar`. Also replacing `woo_sidbar` with `dynamic_sidebar`.

```
// Add widget area above Woocommerce products

add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_sidebar', 40);

function woocommerce_sidebar()
    {
    if (is_woocommerce())
        {
        echo '<div class="filters archive-description content-container-fullwidth">';
        dynamic_sidebar('filters');
        echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```

Thank you everyone for your help. Muz

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [dynamic_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) to spit out the widgets inside the newly created sidebar before the woo main container.

```
add_action( 'woo_main_before', 'woo_sidebar' );
function woo_sidebar() {
    if (is_woocommerce()) { 
        echo '<div class="primary">';
        dynamic_sidebar( 'filters' );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: The code also adds extra sidebars to the footer. How do remove these? See footer on site for an example (http://www.lne.net.au/shop/)

Answer (score 0):

**This solution has been tested on a single product page using Woo Commerce.**

This method works from your child themes functions.php file and is the suggested method for non developers who customize themes.

```
function wpsites_register_woo_widget() {

 register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Before Products Widget',
    'id' => 'before-products',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpsites_register_woo_widget' );

add_filter( 'woo_main_before', 'before_products_widget', 25 );

function before_products_widget() {


        if ( is_product() && is_active_sidebar( 'before-products' ) ) { 
        dynamic_sidebar('before-products', array(
    'before' => '<div class="before-products">',
        'after' => '</div>',
) );


    }

}
```

Here's more about [Woo's conditional tags for Woo Commerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128116/what-is-the-action-hook-code-to-supporting-product-category-condition-in-single/128120#128120)

You can change both the [hook](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/) and conditional tag.

**Note:** If you don't have a child theme created, you can use the Custom Functions section of any Woo themes functions file.