# Woocommerce custom fields

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I'm using woocommerce plugin in my wordpress web site. In Admin panel for products I've added few custom fields as shown bellow:

[image]

On my shop page, I want to print the custom field values, and I use the following code (
my code is inside the `while loop`):

```
 <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'flavour1Title', true); ?>
```

But I get empty string for any retrieved value.

Please can someone explain me what is wrong with my code?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i would use a custom function in your child themes functions file rather than add the code directly to the template file.

You can use the [WooCommerce conditional tags and hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128116/what-is-the-action-hook-code-to-supporting-product-category-condition-in-single/128120#128120) in your code.

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'collection_text', true );
```

Comment: Hm I agree, but it is not working in functions.php niether!

Comment: What exact code did you try in functions?

Comment: I added action for function in my functions.php, and that function should return me get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'flavour1Title', true); custom field called flavour1Title

Comment: I assume you wrapped it correctly in PHP tags?

Answer (score -2):

It would be best to use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to handle your custom field implementation. They offer a free and pro version.

You create your field groups, and have them display in a custom post type (in this case, it would be the WooCommerce custom post type).

You can then call a field while in the loop as simple as `<?php the_field('hero_image'); ?>`

Here is a full example:

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_field('custom_title'); ?></h1>

        <img src="<?php the_field('hero_image'); ?>" />

        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

[Source](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/)

Comment: ACF is a lot more user-friendly too.